# Out of bounds error on addObject to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: cocoa, nsmutabledictionary, indexoutofboundsexception

So I am building an app in cocoa and having a bit of trouble.  I want to feed text file names in many different folders to a tableview using an array controller, but it keeps throwing out of bounds errors.  Heres a chunk of the code giving me trouble.

```
[self clear:nil]; // method that clears the NSTableView

NSString *chooserSelection = chooserItems.titleOfSelectedItem; // gets the selected folder from an NSPopUpButton

if (chooserSelection == @"All") {
    path = @"/Library/Application Support/File Folder/Files/";
    NSArray *folders = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
    NSLog(@"\nfolders = %@", folders);

    for (int i = 0; i < [folders count]; i++) {

            path = @"/Library/Application Support/File Folder/Files/";
            NSMutableString *folderNames = [[NSMutableString stringWithString:path] init];
            [folderNames insertString:folders[i] atIndex:folderNames.length];
            [folderNames insertString:@"/" atIndex:folderNames.length];

            NSArray *text = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderNames error:nil];


        [myArrayController addObject: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:text[i], @"File Name", nil]]; 
        //This line gives the error

    }
}
```

If I change [folders count] to 1 it shows up in the NSTableView.  However on anything past that (additional passes through the for loop) i get an out of bounds error.

```
2013-02-26 13:17:49.679 AppName[3489:403] *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]
2013-02-26 13:17:49.683 AppName[3489:403] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff829b5f56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff84fe6d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8295f370 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 208
    3   AppName                             0x000000010000159a -[AppDelegate tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:] + 106
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff840a16e7 -[NSTableView _dataSourceValueForColumn:row:] + 73
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff840a1167 -[NSTableView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] + 437
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff840b2171 -[NSTableView _drawContentsAtRow:column:withCellFrame:] + 42
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff840b05d8 -[NSTableView drawRow:clipRect:] + 1647
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff840afdb5 -[NSTableView drawRowIndexes:clipRect:] + 565
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff840aded7 -[NSTableView drawRect:] + 1390
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff84197382 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursive:displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inContext:topView:] + 1435
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff841b564f __-[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) drawLayer:inContext:]_block_invoke_1 + 94
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff841b52fb -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) _drawViewBackingLayer:inContext:drawingHandler:] + 2001
    13  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff82c4a0dc -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 145
    14  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff82c49225 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 3221
    15  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff82c4813a _ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev + 1086
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff841504e6 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveDisplayViewsIntoLayersIfNeeded] + 163
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff841505fc -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveDisplayViewsIntoLayersIfNeeded] + 441
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff841505fc -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveDisplayViewsIntoLayersIfNeeded] + 441
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff841505fc -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveDisplayViewsIntoLayersIfNeeded] + 441
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff84150168 -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) _drawRectAsLayerTree:] + 128
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8401653e -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 4382
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8401406d -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 3020
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff84014b5e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 5821
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff84012da3 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 270
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8400e1bb -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 4755
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff84006c35 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1676
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff84006375 _handleWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraints + 648
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff829758e7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82975846 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 374
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8294aaf9 __CFRunLoopRun + 825
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8294a486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    32  AppKit                              0x00007fff84459b08 -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] + 38
    33  AppKit                              0x00007fff842e86f9 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] + 138
    34  AppKit                              0x00007fff841349bb NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 339
    35  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89d08234 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 1263
    36  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89d07840 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 446
    37  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89d1e6db SendEventToEventTarget + 76
    38  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89d647b5 _ZL18SendHICommandEventjPK9HICommandjjhPKvP20OpaqueEventTargetRefS5_PP14OpaqueEventRef + 398
    39  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89e4be2d SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 56
    40  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89e935b5 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 253
    41  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89d5d883 _ZL19FinishMenuSelectionP13SelectionDataP10MenuResultS2_ + 101
    42  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89e8bfed _ZL19PopUpMenuSelectCoreP8MenuData5PointdS1_tjPK4RecttjS4_S4_PK10__CFStringPP13OpaqueMenuRefPt + 1660
    43  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89e8c2ac _HandlePopUpMenuSelection7 + 621
    44  AppKit                              0x00007fff842eb3c5 _NSSLMPopUpCarbonMenu3 + 3860
    45  AppKit                              0x00007fff846990fa _NSPopUpCarbonMenu3 + 39
    46  AppKit                              0x00007fff842e952a -[NSCarbonMenuImpl popUpMenu:atLocation:width:forView:withSelectedItem:withFont:withFlags:withOptions:] + 322
    47  AppKit                              0x00007fff844ca1f1 -[NSPopUpButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 564
    48  AppKit                              0x00007fff840cb7f6 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 786
    49  AppKit                              0x00007fff84096c98 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6306
    50  AppKit                              0x00007fff840303a5 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5593
    51  AppKit                              0x00007fff83fc6a0e -[NSApplication run] + 555
    52  AppKit                              0x00007fff84242eac NSApplicationMain + 867
    53  AppName                             0x0000000100001152 main + 34
    54  AppName                             0x0000000100001124 start + 52
)
```

I can also more the addObject line to the line below the for loop which will display the filename of the last file.  But I cannot figure out where the out of bounds error is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the index i first for the count of folders in path, and then for the count of files in that respective folder. So you are depending on there being at least as many files in folder *N* as the number of *N*.

For example if you have three folders

folder0
folder1
folder2

then when you iterate over folder2 (i=2), there had better be at least 3 items in the folder as you are accessing item 3 (text[2]). When there are fewer items, you will get that out-of-bounds error.

You probably mean to do something like this:

```
        NSMutableDictionary* dict = 
     [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:text, folders[i], nil];
```

That will get you an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary has a single key (the name of the folder,) and a single value (an array of filenames).

You could simplify your data structure further by flattening this to a single dictionary (not inside an array). Each key is a folder name, each value is the array of filenames.